# Best way to create a screen contains details in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a screen as shown in the below image:

[image: example]

I tried to create a code as the below:

```
child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: AppTheme.nearlyWhite,
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 100,
                          left: 20,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child: Container(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Sim Information",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 16,
                              left: 50,
                            ),
                            child: const Text(
                              'Sim Operator',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 16,
                              left: 50,
                            ),
                            child: const Text(
                              'Vodafone',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 30,
                      left: 20,
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: Container(
                            child: Text(
                              "Network Provider",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 16,
                          left: 50,
                        ),
                        child: const Text(
                          'Sim Operator',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 16,
                          left: 50,
                        ),
                        child: const Text(
                          'Vodafone',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 30,
                      left: 20,
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: Container(
                            child: Text(
                              "Serving Cell",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 16,
                          left: 50,
                        ),
                        child: const Text(
                          'Sim Operator',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 16,
                          left: 50,
                        ),
                        child: const Text(
                          'Vodafone',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

But I think it's not logical and not organized as far as I know...

I see that the output not organized as much as I shown in the image..

So I wish someone could recommend me a good solution for this types of screens :)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two widget in flutter to organize your data

1- Table
[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lbE0wsVZSw)
[document](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html)

2- DataTable
[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktTajqbhIcY)
[document](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html)

check witch one is better for your UI

[image]

```
class SimInformation extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Sim information', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
          DataTable(
            columns: [
              DataColumn(label: Text('Sim operator')),
              DataColumn(label: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Vodafone'),
                  Image.asset('assets/images/vodafone.png', width: 30, height: 30,)
                ],
              )),
            ],
            rows: [
              DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset('assets/images/sim.png', width: 30, height: 30,),
                    Text('ICCID'),
                  ],
                )),
                DataCell(Text('123456789')),
              ]),
              DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(Text('IMEI')),
                DataCell(Text('123456789')),
              ]),
              DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(Text('SIM IMSI')),
                DataCell(Text('123456789')),
              ]),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your your answer but it's not a table, may be it's nearly looks like a table, but actually it's not a table, but let me try this and give you the feedback :)

Comment: I edit the answer and add sample code to build first part of that UI

Comment: thanks a lot for your response this is really helped me a lot :D